# Operator Overloading problem with screen insertion operator <<

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I have overloaded all the operators properly but the relational operators are giving me error while using them with `cout` . i have tried alot, it gives this error:

`[Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'GrandInt' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')`

````
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class GrandInt{
    string a;
public:
    GrandInt(){
        a="";
    }
    GrandInt(long long unsigned int n){
        a=to_string(n);
    }
    GrandInt(string n){
        a=n;
    }
    GrandInt(const GrandInt &x){
        a=x.a;
    }
    GrandInt operator+(GrandInt &x){
        char *ap= new char [a.length()+1];
        int al=a.length();
        strcpy(ap,a.c_str());

        char *xp= new char [x.a.length()+1];
        int xl=x.a.length();
        strcpy(xp,x.a.c_str());

        for(;*ap!='\0';ap++){}
        for(;*xp!='\0';xp++){}
        int rl;
        if(xl>al)
            rl=xl+1;
        else
            rl=al+1;
        char *r=new char [rl+1];
        ap--;xp--;
        int ac,xc,sum,cary=0,c=0;
        for(;al>=0||xl>=0;al--,xl--,ap--,xp--,r++,c++){
            if(al>0)
                ac=*ap-48;
            else
                ac=0;
            if(xl>0)
                xc=*xp-48;
            else
                xc=0;
            sum=ac+xc+cary;
                if(sum>9){
                    cary=sum/10;
                    sum=sum%10;
                }
                else
                    cary=0;
            *r=sum+48;
        }
        r--;
        if(*r=='0')
        {   r--;c--;}
         GrandInt temp;
             for(;c>0;c--,r--){
                 temp.a=temp.a+*r;
             }

        return temp;
    }
    GrandInt operator-(GrandInt &x){
            char *ap= new char [a.length()+1];
            int al=a.length();
            strcpy(ap,a.c_str());

            char *xp= new char [x.a.length()+1];
            int xl=x.a.length();
            strcpy(xp,x.a.c_str());

            for(;*ap!='\0';ap++){}
            for(;*xp!='\0';xp++){}
            int rl=al;
            char *r=new char [rl+1];
            ap--;xp--;
            int ac,xc,sum,cary=0,c=0;
            for(;al>=0||xl>=0;al--,xl--,ap--,xp--,r++,c++){
                if(xl>0)
                    xc=*xp-48;
                else
                    xc=0;
                ac=*ap-48;

                if(ac<xc){
                    cary=10;
                    ap--;
                    *ap=*ap-1;
                    ap++;

                }
                sum=ac-xc+cary;
                *r=sum+48;
                cary=0;
            }
            r--;
            if(*r=='0')
            {   r--;c--;}
             GrandInt temp;
                 for(;c>0;c--,r--){
                     temp.a=temp.a+*r;
                 }

            return temp;
        }

    bool operator>(GrandInt &x){
            if(a.compare(x.a)>0)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;

        }

    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out,GrandInt x){
        cout<<x.a;
        return out;
    }
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, GrandInt x){
        cin>>x.a;
        return in;
    }
};

int main()
{
   //starting with small numbers

   GrandInt num1("546");
   GrandInt num2("60");

   cout<<num1+num2<<endl;//606
   cout<<num1-num2<<endl;//486
   cout<<num1>num2<<endl;//1
}```
````

Comment: `cout<<num1>num2<<endl;` should be `cout<<(num1>num2)<<endl;`. See [operator precedence in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: actually no. The operators should read/write from the stream that is passed as parameter, not `cout` / `cin`

Comment: Your`operator>` says that `GrandInt(2) > GrandInt(10)`.

Comment: Why are you messing around with `char*` and dynamic allocation (and lots of memory leaks) when you know about `std::string`?

Comment: Also, stick to `'0'`. It's both more obvious than 48 *and* guaranteed to actually be the zero digit.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `ostream& out` in the overloaded operators. Try this:

```cpp
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, GrandInt x) {
        out << x.a;
        return out;
    }
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, GrandInt x) {
        in >> x.a;
        return in;
    }
```

And in the main function:

```cpp
   cout<< (num1>num2) << endl; // parenthesis needed because of operator precedence
```